# LINQ nested selects is this the most efficient query?

Tags: c#, linq

For educational purposes, I’m rewriting an old MVC web app I created as a web API and trying to get a richer understanding of LINQ. I’m trying to find out the most efficient way to query and sort data from multiple tables using LINQ in code-first EF.

I have a Shift table that holds information for a scheduled work shift. Each shift can have multiple employees assigned (`Shift --<ShiftEmployees>-- Employee`) as well as multiple Activities in various locations, various dress attire and various start times (`Shift --<ShiftActivities>-- Activity/Location/ Uniform`).

The following basic query yields this result:

```
var shift = _context.Shifts
            .Include(s => s.Platoon)
            .Include(s => s.ShiftActivities).ThenInclude(sa => sa.Activity)
            .Include(s => s.ShiftActivities).ThenInclude(sa => sa.Uniform)
            .Include(s => s.ShiftActivities).ThenInclude(sa => sa.Location)
            .Include(s => s.ShiftEmployees).ThenInclude(se =>  se.Employee).ThenInclude(e => e.Rank)
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ShiftID == id);

{
"shiftID": 1,
"shiftDate": "2018-09-03T00:00:00",
"information": null,
"platoon": {
    "platoonID": 2,
    "platoonName": "B Platoon"
},
"shiftEmployees": [
    {
        "shiftEmployeeID": 1,
        "userID": null,
        "pinStatus": 3,
        "employee": {
            "employeeID": 1,
            "serialNumber": "34567",
            "lastName": "Test2",
            "firstName": "Employee",
            "notifyEmail": false,
            "receiptEmail": false,
            "notifySMS": false,
            "receiptSMS": false,
            "rank": {
                "rankID": 1,
                "rankName": "Paygrade III",
                "shortName": "P-III",
                "accessLevel": 1
            },
            "platoon": {
                "platoonID": 2,
                "platoonName": "B Platoon"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "shiftEmployeeID": 2,
        "userID": null,
        "pinStatus": 3,
        "employee": {
            "employeeID": 2,
            "serialNumber": "12345",
            "lastName": "Test",
            "firstName": "Employee",
           .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
            "rank": {
                .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
            },
            "platoon": {
                .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
            }
        }
    }
],
"shiftActivities": [
    {
        "shiftActivityID": 2,
        "startTime": "12:50:05",
        "activity": {
            "activityID": 2,
            "activityName": "1st Muster"
        },
        "location": {
            "locationID": 2,
            "locationCode": 99,
            "locationName": "Location 2",
            "locationAddress": null,
            "locationCity": null,
            "locationZip": null,
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null
        },
        "uniform": {
            "uniformID": 1,
            "uniformName": "A Uniform",
            "uniformDescription": null
        }
    },
    {
        "shiftActivityID": 3,
        "startTime": "15:28:25",
        "activity": {
            .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        },
        "location": {
           .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        },
        "uniform": {
            .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        }
    },
    {
        Additional `shiftActivity` omitted for brevity 
    }
]
}
```

This returns the needed data, however, I want to sort the `ShiftActivities` according to start time, and also sort the `ShiftEmployees` by `Rank`, then `LastName`, then `SerialNumber`. So, I came up with the following query:

```
var shift = _context.Shifts
            .Include(s => s.Platoon)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                shift = s,
                shiftEmployees = s.ShiftEmployees.Select(se => new
                {
                    _shiftEmployee = se,
                    employee = se.Employee,
                    rank = se.Employee.Rank
                }).OrderBy(se => se.employee.LastName)
                  .ThenBy(se =>  se.employee.SerialNumber),
                shiftActivities = s.ShiftActivities.Select(sa => new
                {
                    _shiftActivity = sa,
                    activity = sa.Activity,
                    location = sa.Location,
                    uniform = sa.Uniform,
                }).OrderBy(sa => sa._shiftActivity.StartTime)
            })
            .OrderBy(s => s.shift.Platoon)
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.shift.ShiftID == id);

{
"shift": {
    "shiftID": 1,
    "shiftDate": "2018-09-03T00:00:00",
    "information": null,
    "platoon": {
        "platoonID": 2,
        "platoonName": "B Platoon"
    },
    "shiftEmployees": null,
    "shiftActivities": null
},
"shiftEmployees": [
    {
        "_shiftEmployee": {
            "shiftEmployeeID": 1,
            "userID": null,
            "pinStatus": 3,
            "employee": null
        },
        "employee": {
           "employeeID": 1,
            "serialNumber": "34567",
            "lastName": "Test2",
            "firstName": "Employee",
            "notifyEmail": false,
            "receiptEmail": false,
            "notifySMS": false,
            "receiptSMS": false,
            "rank": null,
            "platoon": null
        },
        "rank": {
                "rankID": 1,
                "rankName": "Paygrade III",
                "shortName": "P-III",
                "accessLevel": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "_shiftEmployee": {
           .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        },
        "employee": {
            .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        },
        "rank": {
            .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        }
    }
],
"shiftActivities": [
    {
        "_shiftActivity": {
            "shiftActivityID": 2,
            "startTime": "12:50:05",
            "activity": null,
            "location": null,
            "uniform": null
        },
        "activity": {
            "activityID": 2,
            "activityName": "1st Muster"
        },
        "location": {
            "locationID": 2,
            "locationCode": 99,
            "locationName": "Location 2",
            "locationAddress": null,
            "locationCity": null,
            "locationZip": null,
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null
        }
        "uniform": {
            "uniformID": 1,
            "uniformName": "A Uniform",
            "uniformDescription": null
        }            
    },
    {
        "_shiftActivity": {
           .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        },
        "activity": {
            .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        },
        "location": {
           .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        },      
        "uniform": {
           .....Other fields omitted for brevity....
        }           
    },
    {
      Additional `shiftActivity` omitted for brevity           
    }
]
}
```

To my human eyes, the first query seems more organized and easier to read, although it’s unsorted the way it needs to be. The second query yields 200 bytes more data (negligible for the low amount of traffic the site would get) and the return times are within a few milliseconds, according to PostMan.

Is my second query the most efficient method to achieve the stated goals? I suppose my desired result would be to sort the data like in the second query while maintaining the structure and readability of the first.

Also, since both approaches pull more data than the user will see (e.g. `notifyEmail/SMS` fields and Platoon information on `Employee`, `accessLevel` in the `Rank`, etc.) is it recommended to use a ViewModel (or data model, since this an API) and only populate the fields I need? ViewModels work well in MVC, but are they necessary in a web API (without getting too far off topic, but I understand if this should be a separate question)? What would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: SO is for code that is not working. You are asking for an opinion, which is off-topic here.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Searching for "efficient linq query" yields over 1400 results, several of which are people asking if their working code is the best way to go about their query, as is mine. Which is why I posted. How else are people supposed to learn to build a better mousetrap?

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just trying to follow the site's [guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions). Mousetrap design is also off-topic. /s

Comment: Mousetrap question posted in another forum :)